# Kubernetes: cert-manager Fails to Issue a Certificate with Let's Encrypt

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate, kubernetes-ingress, lets-encrypt, cert-manager

I am using cert-manager in a Kubernetes cluster to handle certificates from Let's Encrypt. I have set up a `ClusterIssuer`, a `Certificate`, and my `Ingress` to use this certificate, but I'm having trouble getting the certificate issued. Below is a detailed description of the configurations and statuses:

ClusterIssuer Configuration:

```
Name: letsencrypt-prod
Spec:
  Acme:
    Email: xxx@gmail.com
    Private Key Secret Ref:
      Name:  letsencrypt-prod
    Server:  https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    Solvers:
      http01:
        Ingress:
          Class:  nginx
```

Certificate Configuration:

```
Name: frontend-tls
Namespace: default
Spec:
  Dns Names:
    xxx.in
  Issuer Ref:
    Group: cert-manager.io
    Kind: ClusterIssuer
    Name: letsencrypt-prod
  Secret Name: frontend-tls
```

Ingress Configuration:

```
Name: frontend-ingress
Namespace: default
Address: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Ingress Class: nginx
Annotations: cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
```

Error Details:

```
  Name: frontend-tls-nlgtl-2344426666-3388921781
    Status:
      Presented:   false
      Reason:      Error accepting authorization: acme: authorization error for xxx.in: 403 urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized: 3.33.152.147: Invalid response from http://xxx.in/.well-known/acme-challenge/WB9s5TUw3y95tMZPdKVEjMR9mbeh5PhuObAH5Z2FPug: 404
      State:       invalid
```

DNS Configuration:
I confirmed that my domain is pointing to the correct IP:

```
Name:    xxx.in
Addresses:  15.197.345.173
          3.33.234.147
```

Additional Info:
I noticed that the Secret for the certificate is not being created:

```
kubectl get secret frontend-tls -n default
Error from server (NotFound): secrets "frontend-tls" not found
```

I have ensured the following:

1. The DNS records for my domain are set up correctly to point to the
   Ingress Controller’s service IP.
2. My Ingress resource is configured to use this ClusterIssuer.

I am not sure what I am missing or if there is something wrong with my setup. Can anyone help me figure out why cert-manager is failing to issue a certificate? What am I doing wrong here, or what can I do to troubleshoot this issue further?

Answer (score 0):

i'm still new to this but i successfully deployed certificates with Let's Encrypt on a kubernetes cluster and can share my files with you. I used Gandi for my dns but you could use your dns provider instead (if it's not gandi).

My certificate Configuration :

```
# Cert-manager 
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: xxx.space
spec:
  dnsNames:
  - xxx.space
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt
    kind: Issuer
  secretName: secret-tls-one
```

My issuer configuration :

```
# Issuer
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Issuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt
spec:
  acme:
    # The ACME server URL
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory 
    # https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory ORIGINAL
    # https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory TESTS
    email: xxxx@gmail.com
    # Name of a secret used to store the ACME account private key
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt
    solvers:
    - dns01:
        webhook:
          groupName: acme.bwolf.me
          solverName: gandi
          config:
            apiKeySecretRef:
              key: api-token
              name: gandi-credentials1
              namespace: glpi-one
```

My ingress configuration without TLS :

```
# Ingress creation
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: glpi-v1
  namespace: glpi-one
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: glpi
  rules:
  - host: xxx.space
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: glpi-service
            port: 
              number: 80
```

My ingress configuration with TLS :

```
# Ingress creation
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: glpi-v1
  namespace: glpi-one
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    cert-manager.io/issuer: letsencrypt
    cert-manager.io/issuer-kind: Issuer
    cert-manager.io/issuer-group: cert-manager.io
spec:
  ingressClassName: glpi
  rules:
  - host: xxx.space
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: glpi-service
            port: 
              number: 80
  tls: # placing a host in the TLS config will determine what ends up in the cert's subjectAlt
  - hosts:
    - xxx.space
    secretName: secret-tls-one # cert-manager will store the created certificate in this secret.
```

I used a .sh script i created in order to properly do all the steps needed as i can get lost sometimes.

```
# Install cert-manager with custom DNS settings
echo "Installing cert-manager..."
helm install cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager --namespace cert-manager --create-namespace --set installCRDs=true --version v1.10.1 --set 'extraArgs={--dns01-recursive-nameservers=8.8.8.8:53\,1.1.1.1:53}'
echo "Cert-manager installed."

# Install cert-manager-webhook-gandi Helm chart
echo "Installing cert-manager-webhook-gandi Helm chart..."
helm install cert-manager-webhook-gandi --repo https://bwolf.github.io/cert-manager-webhook-gandi --version v0.2.0 --namespace cert-manager --set features.apiPriorityAndFairness=true --set logLevel=6 --generate-name
echo "cert-manager-webhook-gandi Helm chart installed."

# Apply applicative layers
echo "Applying applicative configuration files..."
kubectl apply -f glpi1.yaml -n glpi-one
echo "Applicative configuration files applied"

# Apply Ingress layer
echo "Applying Ingress configuration files..."
kubectl apply -f ingress1_glpiv1.yaml -n glpi-one
echo "Ingress configuration files applied."

# Apply Issuer layer
echo "Applying Let's Encrypt Issuer configuration files..."
kubectl apply -f issuer-glpiv1.yaml -n glpi-one
echo "Let's Encrypt Issuer configuration files applied."

# Create Gandi API token secret
echo "Creating Gandi API token secret..."
kubectl create secret generic gandi-credentials --from-literal=api-token=$apitoken
kubectl create secret generic gandi-credentials1 --from-literal=api-token=$apitoken -n glpi-one
echo "Gandi API token secret created."

# Create role and rolebinding for accessing secrets
echo "Creating role and rolebinding for accessing secrets..."
hookID=$(kubectl get pods -n cert-manager | grep "cert-manager-webhook-gandi-" | cut -d"-" -f5)
kubectl create role access-secrets --verb=get,list,watch,update,create --resource=secrets -n glpi-one
kubectl create rolebinding --role=access-secrets default-to-secrets --serviceaccount=cert-manager:cert-manager-webhook-gandi-$hookID -n glpi-one
echo "Role and rolebinding created."

# Apply Certificate layer
echo "Applying Certificate configuration files..."
kubectl apply -f certif1_glpiv1.yaml -n glpi-one
echo "Certificate configuration files applied."

# Apply Ingress layer
echo "Applying Ingress configuration files..."
kubectl apply -f ingress2_glpiv1.yaml -n glpi-one
echo "Ingress configuration files applied."
```

I don't know if it will help you but this worked for me. I used [bwolf's GitHub repository : cert-manager-webhook-gandi](https://github.com/bwolf/cert-manager-webhook-gandi) so Gandi and ACME can communicate.

When i had issues to deploy certificates, the following commands helped me a lot :

```
kubectl get certificates -n [namespaceName]
kubectl describe certificates -n [namespaceName]
kubectl get orders -n [namespaceName]
kubectl describe orders -n [namespaceName]
```

I used the namespace cert-manager as it is needed for the installation of cert-manager and made sure the secret that contains Gandi API key was in the namespace cert-manager as well.

I hope you will find a solution to your issue :)